# How to eliminate blinded from detection of Aruco marker

Tags: python, objective-c, opencv, aruco

I have an app that detect an aruco marker (original dictionary) in ios using open cv wrapper. 
i have a problem when i am trying to detect markers in outside conditions, like shadow on the aruco or blinded from the sun.

```
-(void) detect:(UIImage *)image {

cv::Mat colorImage, grayImage;
UIImageToMat(image, colorImage);
cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


if (!self.setupDone) {
    self.camParams->CamSize = colorImage.size();
    self.setupDone = true;
}

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
auto mapOfTrackers = *self.mapOfTrackers;
std::vector<aruco::Marker> markers = self.detector->detect(grayImage, *self.camParams, self.markerSize);


for (auto& m : markers) {
    mapOfTrackers[m.id].estimatePose(m, *self.camParams, self.markerSize);
    ArucoMarker *markerObj = [[ArucoMarker alloc] initWithCMarker:m];
    if (markerObj != nil) [result addObject:markerObj];
}

[self.delegate arucoTracker:self didDetectMarkers:result];
```

i already tried to change the threshold settings but no lack

Comment: Please provide your images, without that it's hard to guess

Comment: Part sun and part shade is a very difficult environment to work in due to the very high dynamic range. You can filter out soft-edged shadows using frequency-based filtering in Fourier space, leaving only hard-edged markers, though you may also lose markers which are not in sharp focus. Providing sample images will help a lot to understand your problem.